# python put requests a file

Tags: python, python-requests, put

i'm trying to interact with a website's APIs--specifically how to requests.put() a file (JPEG) to it. the Swagger API has a "try it out" function where I successfully can push a file from its "try it out" but when I try to run it in python it throws a 500 internal server error.

this is the successful curl put request from the Swagger "try it out":

curl -X PUT "https://some_website.com/api/v2/documents" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Authorization: Bearer auth tokenp089u098u08j98jasdfsadgfasdg" -d {"file":{},"metadata":"{ "docType":"BILL_OF_LADING", "docTypeNamespace":"platform", "fileType":"IMAGE", "docReferences":{ "name":"bill o lading pal" }, "identifiers":{ "consignment":{ "carrierBookingNumber":"9876smg", "billOfLadingNumber":"1234smg" } } }"}

```
url = "https://some_website.com"
auth_token = "Bearer auth tokenp089u098u08j98jasdfsadgfasdg"
headers = {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",                  
           "Accept": "*/*", 
           "Authorization": sa_token}
file_loc = "C:/location/of/file/I/want/to/put/Capture.JPG"

metadata = {
    "docType":"doc_file",
    "docTypeNamespace": "platform",
    "fileType":"IMAGE",
    "docReferences": {
        "name": "this is the form to confirm receipt"
    },
    "identifiers": {
        "consignment": {
            "carrierBookingNumber":"9876smg",
            "billOfLadingNumber":"1234smg"
        }
    }
}

body = {
    "file": {},
    "metadata": metadata
}
resp = requests.put(url=url, headers=headers, data=body)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably send it via json as thats very easy...

```
import requets

file = "C:\somedir\somedir\somefile.somext"

with open(file, "rb") as f:
    fileData = f.read()

putFile(fileD, site, port=3000):
    requets.post(site, json='{"file": "' + str(fileD) + '"}'
```

But you'll need to convert it back to a file.